# How do I repair a leak in a ferrocrete overhead water tank?

Tags: water, leak, water-tank

I have a ferrocrete overhead water tank. It has developed a leak at the edge. How do I repair this leak?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I repair a leaking water tank?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/11938/how-can-i-repair-a-leaking-water-tank)

Comment: @steven: not a duplicate; the other is for plastic tanks.

Comment: Is there a crack that is causing the leak or has it become porous and water is penetrating the interior?